# Intel TBB it's 2 time slower than std - tbb vs std

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, concurrency, tbb

I have done a little comparison between 2 programs that are filling a given vector with pseudo-random integers from a mersenne twister, the point is that the TBB version it's terribly slow, the std version is performing the task in about 0.6s when TBB needs at least 1.1s .

I have also noticed that TBB doesn't really offers optimized algorithms to work with containers but it only offers generic constructs ( parallel_for, parallel_for_each and similar ) to work with generic tasks where std offers `std::generate` that is a much better and cleaner solution in this case.

You can download my small test with the 2 small source files + a Makefile for gcc here http://www.sendspace.com/file/ew73h8

I'm doing something wrong here ? the more I increase the size of this vector the slower TBB gets, I'm under Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit with an Intel Q6600.

The TBB version could be better in some way ?

EDIT : full sources for the 2 files

---

**config.hpp**

```
#define N 10000000
```

**std.cpp**

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#include "config.hpp"

int main() {

    std::vector<u_int32_t> v(N);

    std::mt19937 mt;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<u_int32_t> dist(0,499);

    std::generate(v.begin(),v.end(),[&]{return dist(mt);});

    return(0);
}
```

**tbb.cpp**

```
#include <tbb/concurrent_vector.h>
#include <tbb/parallel_for_each.h>

#include <random>
#include <iostream>

#include "config.hpp"

int main()
{
  tbb::concurrent_vector<u_int32_t> v(N);
  std::mt19937 mt;
  std::uniform_int_distribution<u_int32_t> dist(0, 499);
  tbb::parallel_for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),[&](u_int32_t& e){e = dist(mt); });

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Post the code in the question. Most people will not be willing to download an unknown file.

Comment: And explain what is your build/run environment. If you only have a single core, maybe the speedup is lower than the overhead...

Comment: @Massa it's already there, I have a quad core CPU ( without HT but I don't think that this matters )

Comment: @ronag ok, I have done that.

Comment: Is `std::uniform_int_distribution` safe under contended reads from multiple threads?  Try make it `thread_local`, same with `mt`.

Comment: What compilation options are you using? I'm a little surprised the optimiser doesn't discard all the code as "has no observable effect."

Comment: why are u using concurrent_vector, a normal vector would do, each threads is accessing different parts of the vector.

Comment: @Angew it's all in the zip file, I'm compiling both this 2 files with the classic 3 optimization level Os, O2 and O3

Comment: @yngum and why this concurrent thread is non-optimal ?

Comment: @user2485710 writing to concurrent_vector takes a lock. there are many small writes in parallel_for_each. actually it may not take the lock since parallel_for_each just update iterators, I am not sure, try vector to see if it make any difference.

Answer (score 5):

You are sharing the random number generator (RNG) for all the workers that ITBB will control, which, as I see from your question, will be four. Leaving aside the issue of thread safety of mutating the state of the RNG from multiple threads, I would point to the effect on cache: the same memory used by the RNG state is accessed for both reading and writing from four processors, something that most likely renders useless the cache.

Let's try this:

```
#include <tbb/concurrent_vector.h>
#include <tbb/parallel_for_each.h>

#include <vector>
#include <functional>

#include <random>
#include <iostream>

#include "config.hpp"

static thread_local std::mt19937 mt;
static thread_local std::uniform_int_distribution<u_int32_t> dist(0, 499);

int main()
{
  std::vector<u_int32_t> v(N);

  auto f = [&v](std::pair<u_int32_t, u_int32_t> const& p) {
     for (size_t i=p.first; i < p.second; i++)
     {
        v[i] = dist( mt );
     }
  };

  std::vector< std::pair< u_int32_t, u_int32_t > > work;
  work.push_back( std::make_pair( 0, N/2) );
  work.push_back( std::make_pair( N/2, N) );

  tbb::parallel_for_each(
    work.begin(),
    work.end(),
    f 
    );

  return(0);
}
```

Now the time goes down to nearly half of what the std version does (I only have a dual core). What the code does is to force itbb to work in contiguous chunks of memory and instead of distributing the data it distributes the work assignment. I don't think this is the best way of using ITBB, but on the other hand parallel_for_each can not be fed with a block size (from what I see in the [docs](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/algorithms/parallel_for_each_func.htm) ), and doing it with *parallel_for* instead requires some research. But it is not that difficult:

```
#include <tbb/concurrent_vector.h>
#include <tbb/parallel_for.h>

#include <vector>
#include <functional>

#include <random>
#include <iostream>

#include "config.hpp"

static thread_local std::mt19937 mt;
static thread_local std::uniform_int_distribution<u_int32_t> dist(0, 499);

int main()
{
  std::vector<u_int32_t> v(N);

  auto f = [&v](const tbb::blocked_range<u_int32_t>& p) {
     for (auto i=p.begin(); i < p.end(); i++)
     {
        v[i] = dist( mt );
     }
  };

  tbb::parallel_for(
    tbb::blocked_range<u_int32_t>(0,N), 
    f 
    );

  return(0);
}
```

Instead of using ITBB, you might want to use some parallel construct in OpenMP, which  anyway has been bundled with gcc for many years (and you can still use ITBB together with OpenMP, with some care).

What about random numbers and parallel code? They are messy. If you want to seed the RNGs independently and for the clock, the code above will probably suffice. If you want to have reproducible results and uncorrelated RNGs, then you have to take care of each generator being initialized by a thread-specific seed, and the you also need a way of having each seed to touch, through its thread, a deterministic portion of work...

Comment: I can't see a PRNG in the Intel TBB library, what I'm supposed to use or do ?

Comment: actually I got a gain from doing that, the problem is that TBB it's still slower and it's not really respecting the design and implementation of both mersenne and uniform_distribution.

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't really do anything that's that computationally expensive and is also writing to a chunk of memory that is shared between the cores, which will cause frequent invalidation of cache lines. There is a very good chance that the memory access dominates the overall runtime and then parallelizing the access to the shared data structures (with potential locking and similar overhead) will only make that overhead worse.

Also, as dsign mentioned, you introduce additional overhead by sharing the random number generator between the threads which will increase the overhead even more.

Lastly, you're not really comparing apples to apples here. Using any sort of parallel runtime library like Intel's TBB comes at a cost, namely the overhead that this runtime introduces - you have to start it up, the `concurrent_vector` will have access mechanisms like for example locks that introduce additional overhead etc etc. None of this is free and the difference in performance you are seeing might well be attributed simply to the additional runtime overhead that you have created.

Comment: Your last paragraph is a very important point. However, with N=1000000 the amount of work is high enough (close to 3 seconds in my computer) for there to be some gains coming from parallel execution, if it weren't for the memory effect.

Comment: and in what scenario TBB can show a gain over the std ? can you name an example where this overhead it's worth ? I was thinking that a vector of this size was good enough to try something

Comment: You get much better results if your threads work on separate data structures and/or share no state.

Answer (score 1):

What effect does this have...

```
void f(u_int32_t& e)
{
    thread_local std::mt19937 mt;
    thread_local std::uniform_int_distribution<u_int32_t> dist(0, 499);
    e = dist(mt);
}


int main()
{
  tbb::concurrent_vector<u_int32_t> v(N);
  tbb::parallel_for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),f);

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: ok now it compiles and works, this solution makes it a little faster than before but still slower than std, it's a 0.6s vs 0.7s, this also doesn't respect the real uniform int distribution algorithm because of this local thread, Am I right ?

Comment: also how I can get informed about how many threads are spawned by using that `thread_local` storage ?

Comment: The `thread_local` specifier gives the object thread local storage duration.  This means that the first time a given thread encounters the declaration it will construct the object - and the object will then survive until the end of that thread.  Put another way, each thread will have its own instance of the object, so if there are 4 threads there will be four instances of `mt`, and 4 instances of `dist`.

Comment: ok, now i get that, both there is some feedback for that ? How I get the number of threads that have an instance of an object marked as  thread_local ?

Comment: Well you could create an object the writes hello world in its constructor, and then add the hello object as thread_local to `f`, and then run the program and see how many hello worlds get printed.